# How to put the autoincrement value in textbox

Tags: c#, mysql

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        String path = "Data Source=LOCALHOST; Initial Catalog= system; username=root; password=''";
        MySqlConnection sqlconn = new MySqlConnection(path); //communicator //constructors
        MySqlCommand sqlcomm = new MySqlCommand();
        sqlconn.Open();
        sqlcomm.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        sqlcomm.Connection = sqlconn;
        sqlcomm.CommandText = "INSERT INTO maica (Lastname) VALUES ('" + textBox2.Text + "')";
        sqlcomm.ExecuteNonQuery();
        sqlconn.Close();
        MessageBox.Show("Record saved");

   }
```

This is a code in the add button. In phpmyadmin, I checked the autoincrement box. Whenever I run the form, I left the textBox1 which is the ID empty and I input a name in textBox2 which is the Lastname. In phpmyadmin, the ID autoincrements. The textbox1 should have a value of 0001 before I click the add button then after I click the add button, the textBox1 should have 0002. How do I put the autoincrement value in textBox1?This is in winform c#. Sorry for the bad english TIA.

Answer (score 0):

That's the query you need to run together with the insert.

> SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID();

Here's some code to get the ID, first declare a global String somewhere in the class like that

```
private String entryIdString;
```

then

```
    public int insertGetEntryID()
    {

        String sqlquery = "INSERT INTO maica (Lastname) VALUES ('" + textBox2.Text + "'); SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID();";

        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sqlquery, sqlconn);
        try
        {
            sqlconn.Open();

            entryIdStr = command.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
            return int.Parse(entryIdStr);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Exception in DBHandler", ex);
            return -1;
        }
        finally
        {
            sqlconn.Close();
        }

    }
```

This method returns an integer holding the last ID in your table. Now you just set the value to textBox1

```
textBox1.Text = "ID: " + getEntryID();
```

or if you want just the ID

```
textBox1.Text = "" + getEntryID();
```

I was also just about to tell you what Gideon said about you inserting an ID (when if it's set to autoincrement in the DB, you don't need to).

Comment: When I run the form, the value of textBox1 is -1. Its not working :(

Comment: Can you try and execute only the SQL Query in phpmyadmin, see if the query gives you a proper result, it will mean there's a problem with the code.

Comment: It says IDENT_CURRENT does not exist. I changed the query to Select ID from maica, it displayed the ID records. When I run the form, the value of textBox1 is always 1.

Comment: I am sorry, the information I provided about the query was actually wrong, I tested this with my DB and this query works if you execute it together with your insert. I corrected my answer and formatted the query you should put in your code, can you confirm this works?

Comment: I'm truly sorry for the late reply, I tried the code when I run the form the textbox shows the last id no. but when I click the add button, the number in the textbox doesn't generate the next number. And for example the number in textbox is 167 and it goes with the lastname lee, if you look the record in phpmyadmin the lastname lee goes with the ID 168. Btw thanks for the help!

Comment: Could you please post your implementation right now? How you use the code I provided and basically most of the code that you have? I guess we just need to change a few more things.

Answer (score 0):

If your database has an ID column with `AUTO_INCREMENT` set, you do not need to pass a value for the ID into the SQL Insert Statement. You can simply do:

```
sqlcomm.CommandText = "INSERT INTO maica (Lastname) VALUES ('" + textBox2.Text + ')";
```

It is also better to use `SqlCommand` instead of string concatenation as it is protects against SQL Injection and also deals with `Type` and formatting issues.